# How to use Micronaut Security to filter requests? [Micronaut Security 1.3.1]

Tags: java, filter, micronaut

I use JWT Token to secure my application. The setup in application.yml works as expected.

Now I'm trying to filter all request coming to the controllers.

For example:

1. if a request Path variable not match, I want to reject the call with an exceptions for the Frontend.
2. if a request Path variable matched, I want to forward the call to the controller.

I find 2 differents ways to do it: HttpServerFilter and SecurityFilter.

Filter Class:

```
@Filter("/**")
public class MySecurityFilter extends SecurityFilter {

 @Override
 protected Publisher<MutableHttpResponse<?>> doFilterOnce(HttpRequest<?> request,
   ServerFilterChain chain) {
   checkRules(request, chain, null, null, false);
   return super.doFilterOnce(request, chain);
 }

 @Override
 protected Publisher<MutableHttpResponse<?>> checkRules(HttpRequest<?> request,
   ServerFilterChain chain, @Nullable RouteMatch routeMatch,
   @Nullable Map<String, Object> attributes, boolean forbidden) {
   return super.checkRules(request, chain, routeMatch, attributes, forbidden);
 }
}
```

Seems it's looks like SecurityFilter is the better solution, but how to use the checkRules and how doFilterOnce work with it?

Comment: What does JWT and security have to do with your filter implementation?

Comment: Nothing It was some valuable infos I guess. My question was more how to use security filter

Comment: Can you expand on the business rules for your filter? "if a request Path variable not match"